# modern reference for Néron's "Quasi-fonctions et Hauteurs sur les Varietes Abeliennes"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, reference-request, heights, abelian-varieties

Is there a modern reference for Néron's "Quasi-fonctions et Hauteurs sur les Varietes Abeliennes" http://www.jstor.org/pss/1970644 i.e. using Grothendieck's language of schemes and in English?

Comment: Maybe that: http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1172411/?site_locale=en_GB

Comment: You might have a look at Bosch-Lorenzini's paper http://www.math.uga.edu/~lorenz/LorenziniBosch.pdf (§ 4) and Cédric Pépin's preprint http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1103.0570

Comment: I am not sure what topic from that paper you are interested in but you might find some of them in the 'Arithmetic Geometry' volume edited by G. Cornell and J. Silverman: 
http://www.amazon.com/Arithmetic-Geometry-G-Cornell/dp/0387963111/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1323378400&sr=8-2

Comment: Isn't this pretty much the content of Lang's *Fundamentals of Diophantine Geometry*, Chapter 11, "Neron Functions on Abelian Varieties"?